# Prevent blank line at the end of a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have created a program in python that uses a .txt file as a database, so I save the user data there.
The data is stored in the file as follows:

- Each line in the file represents a user
- Users are stored as: `User_ID,First Name,Last Name,Phone Number,Country`

The problem arises when I try to delete a user that is in the last position of the file, because it leaves a blank line that breaks the function of listing the users in the program.

Example:

Suppose I have two users in the text file: [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAnH5.png)

And now I delete the last user (00002): [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPBKX.png)

So, there is a blank line, and when I add a new user, it looks like this: [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOd4v.png)

Here is the code I use to delete users:

```
def delete_user(file, user_id):

    with open(file, 'r+') as f:
        users = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for user in users:
            if user.split(',')[0] != user_id:
                f.write(user)

        f.truncate()
```

Code I use to add users:

```
def add_user(file, first_name, last_name, phone_number, country):

    filesize = os.path.getsize(file)

    with open(file, 'r+') as f:
        if filesize == 0:
            f.write(f'{"1".zfill(5)},{first_name},{last_name},{phone_number},'
                    f'{country}')
        else:
            last_line = f.readlines()[-1]
            user_id = int(last_line.split(',')[0])
            f.write(f'\n{str(user_id+1).zfill(5)},{first_name},{last_name},'
                    f'{phone_number},{country}')
```

Upon investigation, I realized that the problem occurs because there is a newline character (\n) left at the end of the last line, which should not be there.
So, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: don't write the \n at the last line?

Comment: On POSIX systems, there aboslutely should be a newline at the end of every line of a valid text file. This is a common FAQ as such. The proper solution is basically to not `.read.split("\n")` but instead read a full line at a time.

Comment: Like @tripleee said, it is better to leave a newline. You can edit the list function to ignore a newline at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trailing newline shouldn't break your program. You seem to be using a newline as a line *separator*, but on Unix-like OSs, a newline is actually considered a line *terminator*, meaning [there should be one at the end of every line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/4518341).

However, you'll have a much easier time by using a standard data format. What you're using resembles CSV, so I recommend [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), which would also involve putting a column header in the file to label the fields. You might also consider using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/overview.html) (e.g. [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`df.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).